# Where can I get Outlook Express for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, outlook-express

I would like to see Outlook Express installed with Windows 8, or at least be able to download it and install it.  I need it in the 64 bit version.

Comment: use the Mail app which is included in Windows 8.

Comment: Why do you want to use a 5 year old unsupported piece of software that is not even work on Windows 7 let alone Windows 8?  Furthermore there isn't and has NEVER been a 64-bit version of `Outlook Express`.

Comment: @Ramhound There has been 64-bit version of Outlook Express on Windows XP-64 bit (which was quite rare by itself). It used different store folder format, incompatible with 32-bit version. But it is also important to note that practically any 32-bit program will work just fine on 64-bit version of Windows. 64-bits are for programs which need large amounts of memory for example (e.g. more than 4 GB, in practice more than 3.5-3.8 GB), which email programs hardly need.

Answer (score 10):

There's no Outlook Express for Windows 8.

In fact, Outlook Express has been long superseded by Windows Mail in Vista, which in turn was superseded by Windows Live Mail. The latest version of Outlook Express was included in the 2008 Windows XP SP3.

Comment: From what I know Outlook Express doesn't offer anything its successors don't, so I don't see any good reason to use it. You might be able to [install Windows Mail on Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/browsers-mail/3698-how-use-winmail-windows-8-a.html), but why not just use the client that ships with the OS?

Comment: The client that ships with Win8 (Mail) does not support pop3. Also Outlook Express and Windows Mail (pre windows LIVE mail) allowed you to combine pop email accounts and receive all messages in one group. Now each account is separate, a real pain the "a" if you have numerous accounts.

Comment: @slhck "From what I know Outlook Express doesn't offer anything its successors don't, so I don't see any good reason to use it. You might be able to install Windows Mail on Windows 8, but why not just use the client that ships with the OS? – slhck♦ Feb 15 at 19:27" Highly incorrect, With outlook express you had control over your contacts. You could export them, import them, setup and manage groups easily and that's just the start. The contacts issue is a HUGE problem... if you don't believe me just google it. This was a terrible upgrade for a desktop/ workstation computer.

Comment: @drjekyll You can import and export contacts in Outlook 2007, for example, by going to *File » Import and Export*. I haven't worked with it a lot though, and if you think it's lacking functionality, fair enough—I have never used Outlook Express, so I can't comment on specific features, sorry.

Comment: As far as I known OE Classic groups POP3 accounts into single Inbox (unlike Windows Live Mail which forces you to use separated Inboxes) and it can also do address book groups / folders. Another big issue with WAB is that it has never been documented so it can only be accessed using Microsoft WAB API (on Windows XP only). So exporting from Outlook Express 6 can be made using CSV files (called "Text files" in OE6) but that does not preserve or separate groups.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook Express does not exist in Windows 8. It has been abandoned since Windows Vista. On Windows Vista it has been replaced by built-in **Windows Mail** which has been removed on Windows 7. For Windows 7, Microsoft offered **Windows Live Mail** as an download option, part of the **Windows Live Essentials** package. On Windows 8 a **Mail App** for Windows has been offered.

If you look outside of Microsoft offering you can find quite a lot of different or replacement programs (some also resemble the user-interface of the Outlook Express).

**Microsoft options:**

- [Windows Live Mail](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/essentials-other) (no longer available)
- [Outlook](https://products.office.com/) (part of the Microsoft Office package)
- [Mail App](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/mail-app-tutorial) (Built in Windows 8 and Windows 10)
- [Outlook.com](https://www.outlook.com) (Web mail, former Live / MSN / Hotmail)

**Non-Microsoft options:**

- [OE Classic](https://www.oeclassic.com/) (Replacement for Outlook Express - your best option)
- [Postbox](https://www.postbox-inc.com/)
- [eM Client](http://www.emclient.com/)
- [The Bat!](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/)
- [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/)

Many, many more are compared on [Wikipedia Comparison page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients).